# How do you get the directory name from the error object on IOError in python 2.3.4?

Tags: python, python-2.3

When trying to open a directory, an exception is thrown:

```
>>> try:
...   open( '/' )
... except IOError, e:
...   print e.filename
None
```

Is it possible (preferrably in python 2.3.4) for the handler of the exception to get the name of the directory from the exception object?

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of python?

Comment: @nathan I ask this question nearly every day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in older versions of Python: http://bugs.python.org/issue4764

Supplying the open function with a mode, `open('/', 'r')`, might allow you to retrieve the filename via `e.filename`.